# Sitecore schedule task not running on the XP scaled environment (CM server)

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks

We’ve configured Sitecore schedule task, which runs at every 1 hour. The schedule task is running fine after deployment/web app restart but after sometime it’s not working as expected.

We’ve verified below points:

1. Database agent is configured for the master database (yes, it’s)
2. `Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeScheduler` pipeline processor isn’t deleted with custom patch file (no, it’s not)
3. `INFO` entries for the **Scheduler - Adding agents** in the Sitecore log file (yes, it’s)
4. `Application pool` not cycled down (no, it’s not. Checked Sitecore logs and verified the `keepalive.aspx` url hitting at the specified interval (10 minutes) by UrlAgent)
5. Verified the Sitecore schedule task’s schedule value (it’s 20160101|99990101|127|01:00:00)

**Additional Notes:**

- The `Async` is checked and the Schedule task is taking 5-7 minutes to complete (referred https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/do-you-know-why-you-check-async-checkbox-while-configuring-scheduled-task/)
- Verified the Sitecore logs and found **Starting: Import Data** and **Starting: Import Data** entries (the **Last run** field value is updating but actual code isn't executing and there isn't any error in the logs, the same schedule task is working on the XP Standalone environment)
- Sitecore Version: Sitecore 9.0-update-2
- Topology: XP-Scaled
- Deployment Environment: Azure

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Do you have more than on CM Server in scaled environment setup.?

Comment: @Gobinath - No, we are having single CM server.

Comment: @BhaveshManiya: Did you find something?  Is it necessary to have it as async in Azure XP?

Comment: @NutsAndBolts - Sorry, was busy with lot many things. No, I haven’t found anything basically moved to different project. Regarding async option, it’s not necessary (please refer above Kiran Patil's blog)

Comment: @BhaveshManiya Have you checked the frequency interval and Sitecore.Tasks.TaskDatabaseAgent interval you need to set value there. And if you are trying to publish something on this scheduler then you also need to check Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent interval.